# ERROR 1064 (42000) while running mysql dump

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

using this command :

```
mysqldump -u root -p root db1 user > abc.sql;
```

I receive the following error

> error : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p root db1 user > abc.sql' at line 1

Comment: Type `mysqldump /?` on Windows or `mysqldump --help` on *nix, and read what it accepts as command line arguments and how they are used. Or do exactly what the error message tells you, and check the manual for the MySQL version you're using, which you can find easily by using your favorite web search engine to look for `MySQL documentation`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run this from the MySQL client, when you should just run it from the command line.